# Question on CodeEffects Rule Engine capabilities: client connected to remote business-rules server/engine

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I am working on a .NET Core project where a client needs to connect to a remote business-rule server/engine, fire all or specific rules and get back responses. Like "kieserveradapter" (https://github.com/tenkyu/KieServerAdapter) that connects and fires rules created in jBPM.
Is this possible with CodeEffects? Can anyone give some hints or even a demo code?

Answer (score 0):

Code Effects rules are simple XML strings. You can store them in any global database, or a file system, or any other type of global storage.
Our engine is implemented in a separate dll. You can easily reference it in any of your services, add an end point that takes your source object(s) and your rule(s) or rule ID(s) as parameters and returns your evaluated source and evaluation result(s), and invoke that end point from any other resource. This is pretty much the most efficient way of implementing Code Effects engine in large systems.

We need some more details on your use case in order to provide specifics.